# libphidget cross building, libusb_init no, and cannot find usb.h

Tags: linux, compilation

Here is the operation steps, help me:

> charlie@charlie-desktop:~/libphidget-ARM$ ./configure --prefix=/home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/bin/ --host=arm-linux
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>   checking for arm-linux-strip... arm-linux-strip
>   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for mawk... mawk
>   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>   checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
>   checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
>   checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking how to print strings... printf
>   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
>   checking for arm-linux-gcc... arm-linux-gcc
>   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>   checking for suffix of executables...
>   checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
>   checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>   checking whether arm-linux-gcc accepts -g... yes
>   checking for arm-linux-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>   checking whether arm-linux-gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
>   checking dependency style of arm-linux-gcc... gcc3
>   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
>   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
>   checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
>   checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
>   checking for ld used by arm-linux-gcc... /home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/arm-ntc-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld
>   checking if the linker (/home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/arm-ntc-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
>   checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... //home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/bin/arm-linux-nm -B
>   checking the name lister (//home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/bin/arm-linux-nm -B) interface... BSD nm
>   checking whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
>   checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
>   checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
>   checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to arm-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
>   checking how to convert i686-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
>   checking for /home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/arm-ntc-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
>   checking for arm-linux-objdump... arm-linux-objdump
>   checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
>   checking for arm-linux-dlltool... no
>   checking for dlltool... no
>   checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
>   checking for arm-linux-ar... arm-linux-ar
>   checking for archiver @FILE support... @
>   checking for arm-linux-strip... (cached) arm-linux-strip
>   checking for arm-linux-ranlib... arm-linux-ranlib
>   checking command to parse //home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/bin/arm-linux-nm -B output from arm-linux-gcc object... ok
>   checking for sysroot... no
>   checking for arm-linux-mt... no
>   checking for mt... mt
>   configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
>   checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
>   checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-linux-gcc -E
>   checking for ANSI C header files... yes
>   checking for sys/types.h... yes
>   checking for sys/stat.h... yes
>   checking for stdlib.h... yes 
>   checking for string.h... yes
>   checking for memory.h... yes
>   checking for strings.h... yes
>   checking for inttypes.h... yes
>   checking for stdint.h... yes
>   checking for unistd.h... yes
>   checking for dlfcn.h... yes
>   checking for objdir... .libs
>   checking if arm-linux-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
>   checking for arm-linux-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
>   checking if arm-linux-gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
>   checking if arm-linux-gcc static flag -static works... yes
>   checking if arm-linux-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
>   checking if arm-linux-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
>   checking whether the arm-linux-gcc linker (/home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/arm-ntc-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
>   checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
>   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
>   checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
>   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build static libraries... yes
>   checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
>   checking for arm-linux-gcc... (cached) arm-linux-gcc
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
>   checking whether arm-linux-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
>   checking for arm-linux-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
>   checking whether arm-linux-gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
>   checking dependency style of arm-linux-gcc... (cached) gcc3
>   checking for ldconfig... /sbin/ldconfig
>   checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl
>   checking for library containing sqrt... -lm
>   checking for library containing pthread_join... -lpthread
>   checking for library containing iconv... none required
>   checking for library containing libusb_init... no   // ----> something wrong?
>   checking for library containing usb_find_busses... -lusb
>   checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
>   configure: creating ./config.status
>   config.status: creating Makefile
>   config.status: creating examples/Makefile
>   config.status: creating libphidget21.pc
>   config.status: executing depfiles commands
>   config.status: executing libtool commands
>   charlie@charlie-desktop:~/libphidget-ARM$ make
>
> ```
>  CC       cusblinux.lo
> ```
>
> linux/cusblinux.c:23:17: fatal error: usb.h: No such file or directory
>      #include 
>                     ^
>      compilation terminated.
>      Makefile:963: recipe for target 'cusblinux.lo' failed
>      make: *** [cusblinux.lo] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the usb.h header file. You can solve it in two ways.

One is providing the path of usb.h using **CFLAGS**

```
./configure CFLAGS=-I<path/to/usb.h>
```

Or the other way is exporting the **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** variable

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<path/to/the/pkg-config-file>
```

To cross compile libusb follow the below steps

```
./configure --prefix=/home/charlie/SDK_Bovine_vdf_nwl12_2.0.18.9/compiler/bin/ --host=arm-linux
```

Then compile it

```
make
```

Finally install it

```
make install
```

Comment: If using the default PC compiling tool, the compiling is ok. But if changing to cross compiling, something wired.

Comment: Have you cross compiled libusb-1.0?  I checked cross compiling libphidget and it is cross compiled successfully

Comment: Hi, I did not cross compiling the libusb-1.0, do i need to download the source code, then compiling it?

Comment: Yes you have to dowload libusb and compile it. If you need any help reagrding that you can ask.

Comment: Yes, please give a quick guide for the cross compiling. what the command of configure. Thanks.